# Effective way to Join ArrayList

Tags: java, join, dictionary, arraylist

I am looking for an effective way to create a list/map etc out of the below two lists, which I can use to get both current and past status of a rule.

```
            List<Boolean> rulesCurrentStatus = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); // 3 Rules: false/true meaning if the rule passed of failed
             rulesCurrentStatus.add(false);
             rulesCurrentStatus.add(true);
             rulesCurrentStatus.add(false);

            List<Boolean> rulesPreviousStatus = new ArrayList<Boolean>();  // Previous state of the above 3 rules.

            rulesPreviousStatus.add(true);
            rulesPreviousStatus.add(true);
            rulesPreviousStatus.add(false);
```

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you want to create a list containing these 6 booleans? If you want a map, what would be the keys and values of the map?

Comment: It's unclear what you want, please elaborate.

Comment: We need more detail on exactly what you're trying to achieve - what is the scenario, are there only ever 3 values, do you need to be able to lookup individual values or just get the 3 current and the 3 previous values... and what exactly is wrong with the current approach?

Comment: I just dont want to add the two list. I was asking if there is a kind of data structure in which I can store current and previous values. For eg : In list I can `rulesPreviousStatus.add(true);` I am looking for something like `rulesPreviousStatus.add(true,false);`. More like a multidimensional list. May be I should create an ArrayList and add the above two arrayLists in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map with key of String type and value of Boolean type. You can differentiate between current and previous value using the key. e.g. Store all current values with key something similar C#1,C#2 and store previous values with key something similar P#1, P#2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you right, you want to get the status history of a rule. 
then maybe this could help:

```
Map<Rule( or ruleName as String), List<Boolean>>
```

the key in that map is the rule object or e.g. a String indicate which rule. the value is a list (ArrayList for example), stores the status history. for example:

```
{"rule1":[True, False,True]   //1st,2nd,3rd(current) status
"rule2":[True,False]
...
}
```

thus if you want to get the whole status-history of a rule by

```
List<Boolean> history =   map.get("someRule")
```

then you could add new status, or get certain status by playing with the List.

if you only need pre and current, you could declare the List with initial capacity.

Comment: Even this works, or it can be also a list containing two list, one with currentStatus other with previousStatus. By statusHistory I actually meant just the previousStatus. Thanks for showing another way.

Comment: @Himalay if I were you, I won't go with "a list containing two list" way

Comment: Neither I am :), that would increase the parse complexity